# How can I load data that can't be pickled in each Spark executor?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using the [NoAho library](https://github.com/JDonner/NoAho) which is written in Cython. Its internal trie [cannot be pickled](https://github.com/JDonner/NoAho/issues/4): if I load it on the master node, I never get matches for operations that execute in workers.

Since I would like to use the same trie in each Spark executor, I found a way to load the trie lazily, inspired by this [spaCy on Spark issue](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/125#issue-109689721).

```
global trie

def get_match(text):
    # 1. Load trie if needed
    global trie
    try:
        trie
    except NameError:
        from noaho import NoAho

        trie = NoAho()
        trie.add(key_text='ms windows', payload='Windows 2000')
        trie.add(key_text='ms windows 2000', payload='Windows 2000')
        trie.add(key_text='windows 2k', payload='Windows 2000')
        ...

    # 2. Find an actual match to get they payload back
    return trie.findall_long(text)
```

While this works, all `.add()` calls are performed for every Spark job, which takes around one minute. Since I'm not sure "Spark job" is the correct term, I'll be more explicit: I use Spark in a Jupyter notebook, and every time I run a cell that needs the `get_match()` function, the trie is never cached and takes one minute to load the tries, which dominates the run time.

Is there anything I can do to ensure the trie gets cached? Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by cached? How do you use it?

Comment: @zero323 What I mean is that I go through the `except NameError` part every time, replaying the `trie.add()` calls. I would have hoped to do that only once. Afterwards, I use the trie in a .map() call in order to retrieve the payload (see my edit). Does that answer your question?

Comment: More or less. So you add to trie is static?

Comment: @zero323 Yes! Feel free to ask more questions, I'll try my best to make my answers clear.

Comment: That's interesting. Which cluster manager do you use? And could check `spark.python.worker.reuse` setting?

Comment: I'm using yarn. I don't know how to check a setting yet, I'll try to find this in the pyspark API. I'll also try to see if setting up the cluster [this way](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/tutorials/jupyter-notebook) (we're using Google Dataproc) instead of our current setup will improve things.

Comment: Generally speaking your method looks sane. One possible improvement is to use singleton modules but if interpreters are not reused it won't help.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the sanity check @zero323! Here's [SparkConf().getAll() for reference](https://gist.github.com/pquentin/a2a23898a59878789066) - no mention of `spark.python.worker.reuse`. I'll try the other setup next.

Comment: So it should be default (true).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103956/discussion-between-quentin-pradet-and-zero323).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is to use a singleton module to load and initialize the `trie`. Basically all you need is a separate module with something like this:

- `trie_loader.py`

  ```
  from noaho import NoAho

  def load():
      trie = NoAho()
      trie.add('ms windows', 'Windows 2000')
      trie.add('ms windows 2000', 'Windows 2000')
      trie.add('windows 2k', 'Windows 2000')
      return trie

  trie  = load()
  ```

and distribute this using standard Spark tools:

```
sc.addPyFile("trie_loader.py")
import trie_loader

rdd = sc.parallelize(["ms windows", "Debian GNU/Linux"])
rdd.map(lambda x: (x, trie_loader.trie.find_long(x))).collect()
## [('ms windows', (0, 10, 'Windows 2000')),
##  ('Debian GNU/Linux', (None, None, None))]
```

This should load required data every time Python process executor is started instead of loading it when data is accessed. I am not sure if it can help here but it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not make it work yet. Indeed, as soon as I do `from trie_loader import trie`, the trie gets loaded on the Spark master. If I use it in a `map()`, it gets pickled empty to the slaves, and I don't get any match. Am I explaining the solution clearly? Did I implement your solution incorrectly?

Comment: While this works, I believe a new trie is created each time just like in my question. Anyway, I found a way to load only the data I need which "resolves" the issue on my end for now (but I'll need a way bigger trie at some point, unfortunately). Thank you again for your efforts on this question.

Comment: I am out of ideas. I'm pretty sure it should work as long as Python processes are kept alive. There is some chance that [dennis-huo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3777211/dennis-huo) can provide some dataproc specific insight.

Comment: Isn't this a non-answer if it creates a new trie everytime?

Comment: @rado I believe it is a valid answer. It won't help you if there is a intensive rotation of executors (for example with dynamic allocation) but there is not trivial (without external service) way to preserve state beyond a lifetime of a an individual executor process.